# Prove that $F'(x) = \int\limits_0^\infty f_1(x,y) dy$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f$ measurable in 2 variables $x >0$ and $y>0$ and assume that:

1. For every $y >0$, $x \rightarrow f(x,y)$ decreases monotonically to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$
2. For every $y >0$, $F(x) =\int\limits_0^\infty f(x,y) dy < \infty$
3. $f_1(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ continuous in both $x$ and $y$

Prove:

1. $F(x) = -\int\limits_x^\infty \int\limits_0^\infty f_1(t,y) dy dt$ for all $x >0$
2. $F'(x) = \int\limits_0^\infty f_1(x,y) dy$ for almost all $x$

I have proved the first statement. I am having trouble with the second.

Comment: Some variation of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem may be useful, which states that if $h$ is integrable on the real line, $H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x h(t)dt$ is differentiable almost everywhere with $H'(x) = h(x)$.

Comment: Also hypothesis #2 should read that for every $y > 0$, $F(x) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)dy < \infty$.

Comment: Is there another way that does not involve lebesgue differentation theorem on the real line? All I have learned is lebesgue differentation theorem on bounded interval